If $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f:X\to\Bbb [0,\infty)$ measurable, prove $F(y)=\mu(f^{-1}(\{y\}))$ is Borel measurable.
Since the space is $\sigma-$finite, there exists a sequence $\{X_n\}$ such that $X=\bigcup X_n$ and $\mu(X_n)<\infty$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.
The most I've tried to do was to put $$F(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X \chi_{f^{-1}(\{y\})\cap X_n}d\mu$$
to see if there was a limit of functions easier to prove they are measurable and also tried to see if $F^{-1}((a,\infty))$ or $F^{-1}([0,a))$ for $a\geq0$ are some numerable union or intersection of known Borel measurable sets but I'm really stuck.
I'd like to know some hints to start.

Here is a tedious alternative to @geetha290krm's slick proof.
If we can show that $F_m(y) = \mu( f^{-1}(\{y\}) \cap ( X_1 \cup ... \cup X_m))$ is measurable, then since $F$ is the pointwise limit of $F_m$ it would follow that $F$ is measurable. Hence it is sufficient to prove the result assuming that the measure space is finite.
Let $\underline{d_n}(x) = {\lfloor 2^n x \rfloor \over 2^n}$,
$\overline{d_n}(x) = {\lceil 2^n x \rceil \over 2^n}$, note that
$\underline{d_n}(x) \le \underline{d_{n+1}}(x) \le x \le \overline{d_{n+1}}(x) \le \overline{d_n}(x)$, and $\underline{d_n}(x) \to x$ and $\overline{d_n}(x) \to x$. Note that for on $[0,\infty)$, both $\underline{d_n}, \overline{d_n}$ can be written in the form $x \mapsto \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}(x)$ where $\alpha_k \ge 0$ are distinct and the $A_k$ are disjoint intervals.
Let me call a function of the form $x \mapsto \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}(x)$ an extended simple function. It is straightforward to check that such a function is measurable.
Let $\underline{F_n}(y) = \mu(f^{-1}([0,\underline{d_n}(y)))$ and $\overline{F_n}(y) = \mu(f^{-1}([0,\overline{d_n}(y)]))$, then both can be written as extended simple functions and hence are measurable. Taking limits, we see that $\underline{F}(y) = \mu(f^{-1}([0,y)))$ and $\overline{F}(y) = \mu(f^{-1}([0,y]))$ are measurable, and since $F=\overline{F}- \underline{F}$, we see that $F$ is measurable.

@Snoop Yes to the first, and thanks for catching that. The 'd' functions are just lower & upper step approximations to the function $x \mapsto x$. The point being that the set $[0,\underline{d}_n([0,y))$ 'grows' to $[0,y)$ and similarly the other shrinks to same.

@Snoop I don't understand what you mean by $\underline{d}_n[0,y)$, $\underline{d}_n$ is a map $[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$. The idea being that ${y} = [0,y] \setminus [0,y) = ( \cap_n [0,\overline{d}_n] ) \setminus ( \cup_n [0,\underline{d}_n) )$.

@Snoop the other answers (including yours) are more straightforward. I added the above as it illustrates a popular approach to showing measurability (step approximations).

I took a look again, and I fully understand now. deleted my comments. Thank you!

@Snoop No need to delete. I think the comment trails contain much useful information.

Here is yet another approach which is based on the fact that $\{y:\mu(f^{-1}(\{y\}))>0\}$ is at most countable - to see this, reprise the argument in this answer by substituting $([0,\infty),\mathscr{B}[0,\infty),\lambda)$ with $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ and $([0,n])_n$ with $(X_n)_n$. Let $(y_n)_n$ be an enumeration of $\{y:\mu(f^{-1}(\{y\}))>0\}$, we get then
$$F(y)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu(f^{-1}(\{y_n\}))\mathbf{1}_{\{y_n\}}(y)$$
which is a linear combination of nonnegative Borel functions, and is thus Borel.

Nice observation.
